# Problem in Nginx HTTPS with Certbot and docker container application

Tags: docker, http, nginx, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

Need help to set up a nginx https using certbot that forwards to a docker container application open on `0.0.0.0:8080`

I have set up docker on a VPS (IONOS) and firewall rules to all ports open.
The application can be accessed by ip:8080 before installing and starting nginx

First I am new to nginx so I don't know whether to use nginx or nginx docker as I want to forward all requests to the docker container application.

Nginx config at `./etc/nginx/site-avliable/defalut`

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name incog.rioctos.com www.incog.rioctos.com;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }
}
```

This just returns a 502 error.

I got a problem with certbot acme-challenge with the connection refused, I have opened a topic at `https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-challenges-failed-connection-refused/196892/1`

Thanks to anyone for any suggestions.

I have tried a different nginx config, just returns a 502 error. Expecting request to be forwarded to docker application open on 0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: your question looks very similar to mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76118323/certbot-wants-nginx-running-to-complete-acme-challenge-but-nginx-wants-certbot-c