# Certbot wants nginx running to complete ACME challenge but NGINX wants certbot certificates to exist in order to run

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, certbot

- I have spent more than 3 days on this issue
- I am trying to deploy a node.js app that runs inside docker-compose on AWS EC2 Amazon Linux 2
- I double checked that 80 and 443 ports are open in ec2 security groups and that the instance is using this security group
- I have a container for node.js, postgres, redis and one for nginx and certbot

When I run it currently on EC2, I get this error

```
certbot_prod          | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot_prod          | Account registered.
certbot_prod          | Requesting a certificate for ch.com and 3 more domains
certbot_prod          | 
certbot_prod          | Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
certbot_prod          |   Domain: api.ch.com
certbot_prod          |   Type:   connection
certbot_prod          |   Detail: 54.219.246.15: Fetching http://api.ch.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/_WkeLWtnnZAeyhQdiDfZKI1azYIXwO_8U7_4iITOl2M: Connection refused
certbot_prod          | 
certbot_prod          |   Domain: ch.com
certbot_prod          |   Type:   connection
certbot_prod          |   Detail: 54.219.246.15: Fetching http://ch.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/KtNX_s9kglcw1LF1I2uq5c560Zh2qS1O2NWNX_Pohyc: Connection refused
certbot_prod          | 
certbot_prod          |   Domain: www.api.ch.com
certbot_prod          |   Type:   connection
certbot_prod          |   Detail: 54.219.246.15: Fetching http://www.api.ch.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/hqBWwi-QPLgZEZ7TfQR6pP613XFVpXwsDi7SOfTD0rM: Connection refused
certbot_prod          | 
certbot_prod          |   Domain: www.ch.com
certbot_prod          |   Type:   connection
certbot_prod          |   Detail: 54.219.246.15: Fetching http://www.ch.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/Ev6av-kB9UDaZnDiPQJg603a1nGDsorayApfhlRXw_M: Connection refused
certbot_prod          | 
certbot_prod          | Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the temporary challenge files created by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains serve their content from the provided --webroot-path/-w and that files created there can be downloaded from the internet.
certbot_prod          | 
certbot_prod          | Some challenges have failed.
certbot_prod          | Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
web_server_prod       | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
web_server_prod       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
web_server_prod       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
web_server_prod       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
web_server_prod       | 2023/04/26 13:57:30 [warn] 1#1: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:4
web_server_prod       | nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:4
web_server_prod       | 2023/04/26 13:57:30 [emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
web_server_prod       | nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
web_server_prod       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
web_server_prod       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
web_server_prod       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
web_server_prod       | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
web_server_prod       | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
web_server_prod       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
web_server_prod       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
web_server_prod       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
web_server_prod       | 2023/04/26 13:57:32 [warn] 1#1: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:4
web_server_prod       | nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:4
web_server_prod       | 2023/04/26 13:57:32 [emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
web_server_prod       | nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

I am not an expert by any means on docker, certbot or nginx but the way I understand it is that certbot fails because nginx is not running for completing its ACME validation but nginx fails because it doesn't have the certificates from certbot

**Project Folder Structure**

[image]

**docker-compose.yaml file**

```
version: '3.9' # optional since v1.27.0
name: ch_api_prod
services:
  api_server_prod:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: ./docker/production/api_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: api_server_prod
    depends_on:
      cache_server_prod:
        condition: service_healthy
      database_server_prod:
        condition: service_healthy
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: api_server_prod_image
    networks:
      - network
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - '21347:21347'

  cache_server_prod:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/production/cache_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: cache_server_prod
    env_file:
      - .env
    healthcheck:
      test:
        ['CMD-SHELL', 'redis-cli -p 23431 -a $REDIS_PASSWORD ping | grep PONG']
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
    image: cache_server_prod_image
    networks:
      - network
    ports:
      - '23431:23431'
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - cache_volume:/data

  certbot:
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/_letsencrypt --email ch@gmail.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging -d ch.com  -d www.ch.com -d api.ch.com  -d www.api.ch.com
    container_name: certbot_prod
    depends_on:
      web_server_prod:
        condition: service_started
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot_etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot_var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - web_server_root:/var/www/_letsencrypt

  database_server_prod:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/production/database_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: database_server_prod
    env_file:
      - .env
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          'CMD-SHELL',
          "pg_isready -d 'host=database_server_prod user=ch_api_user port=26189 dbname=ch_api_db'",
        ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
    image: database_server_prod_image
    networks:
      - network
    ports:
      - '26189:26189'
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - database_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  dhparam_prod:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/production/dhparam/Dockerfile
    container_name: dhparam_prod
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: dhparam_prod_image
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - dhparam:/home/dhparam

  web_server_prod:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/production/web_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: web_server_prod
    depends_on:
      api_server_prod:
        condition: service_started
      dhparam_prod:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    image: web_server_prod_image
    networks:
      - network
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - certbot_etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot_var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - web_server_conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - web_server_root:/var/www/_letsencrypt
      - dhparam:/etc/ssl/certs

networks:
  network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  cache_volume:
    driver: local
  certbot_etc:
    driver: local
  certbot_var:
    driver: local
  dhparam:
    driver: local
  web_server_conf:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/ec2-user/api/docker/production/web_server/nginx
      o: bind
  web_server_root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/ec2-user/api/_letsencrypt
      o: bind
  database_volume:
    driver: local
```

**web_server Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.23.3
COPY --chown=nginx:nginx ./docker/production/web_server/nginx/ /etc/nginx/
```

**nginx.conf file**

```
# Generated by nginxconfig.io
# See nginxconfig.txt for the configuration share link

user                 nginx;
pid                  /tmp/nginx.pid;
worker_processes     auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

# Load modules
include              /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    multi_accept       on;
    worker_connections 65535;
}

http {
    charset                utf-8;
    sendfile               on;
    tcp_nopush             on;
    tcp_nodelay            on;
    server_tokens          off;
    log_not_found          off;
    types_hash_max_size    2048;
    types_hash_bucket_size 64;
    client_max_body_size   16M;

    # MIME
    include                mime.types;
    default_type           application/octet-stream;

    # Logging
    access_log             off;
    error_log              /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    # Limits
    limit_req_log_level    warn;
    limit_req_zone         $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=10r/m;

    # SSL
    ssl_session_timeout    1d;
    ssl_session_cache      shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets    off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites
    ssl_dhparam            /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

    # Mozilla Intermediate configuration
    ssl_protocols          TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers            ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;

    # OCSP Stapling
    ssl_stapling           on;
    ssl_stapling_verify    on;
    resolver               1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout       2s;

    # Connection header for WebSocket reverse proxy
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ""      close;
    }

    map $remote_addr $proxy_forwarded_elem {

        # IPv4 addresses can be sent as-is
        ~^[0-9.]+$        "for=$remote_addr";

        # IPv6 addresses need to be bracketed and quoted
        ~^[0-9A-Fa-f:.]+$ "for=\"[$remote_addr]\"";

        # Unix domain socket names cannot be represented in RFC 7239 syntax
        default           "for=unknown";
    }

    map $http_forwarded $proxy_add_forwarded {

        # If the incoming Forwarded header is syntactically valid, append to it
        "~^(,[ \\t]*)*([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?(;([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?)*([ \\t]*,([ \\t]*([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?(;([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?)*)?)*$" "$http_forwarded, $proxy_forwarded_elem";

        # Otherwise, replace it
        default "$proxy_forwarded_elem";
    }

    # Load configs
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # api.ch.com
    server {
        listen                               443 ssl http2 reuseport;
        listen                               [::]:443 ssl http2 reuseport;
        server_name                          www.api.ch.com;
        root                                 /var/www/_letsencrypt;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate                      /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key                  /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate              /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/chain.pem;

        # security headers
        add_header X-XSS-Protection          "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options    "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy           "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy   "default-src 'self' http: https: ws: wss: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self';" always;
        add_header Permissions-Policy        "interest-cohort=()" always;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

        # . files
        location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
            deny all;
        }

        # security.txt
        location /security.txt {
            return 301 /.well-known/security.txt;
        }

        location = /.well-known/security.txt {
            alias ~/security.txt;
        }

        # logging
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined buffer=512k flush=1m;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

        # reverse proxy
        location / {
            proxy_pass                         http://api_server_prod:21347;
            proxy_set_header Host              $host;
            proxy_http_version                 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;

            # Proxy SSL
            proxy_ssl_server_name              on;

            # Proxy headers
            proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection        $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Forwarded         $proxy_add_forwarded;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

            # Proxy timeouts
            proxy_connect_timeout              60s;
            proxy_send_timeout                 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout                 60s;
        }

        # favicon.ico
        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
        }

        # robots.txt
        location = /robots.txt {
            log_not_found off;
        }

        # gzip
        gzip            on;
        gzip_vary       on;
        gzip_proxied    any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_types      text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;
    }

    # non-www, subdomains redirect
    server {
        listen                  443 ssl http2;
        listen                  [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name             .api.ch.com;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/chain.pem;

        # logging
        error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
        return                  301 https://www.api.ch.com$request_uri;
    }

    # HTTP redirect
    server {
        listen      80 reuseport;
        listen      [::]:80 reuseport;
        server_name .api.ch.com;

        # logging
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

        # ACME-challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            allow all;
            root /var/www/_letsencrypt;
        }

        location / {
            return 301 https://www.api.ch.com$request_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I break this this cyclic dependency. I dont want to do anything manually as I need to run this on EC2 and update it whenever something in my application changes. Can someone kindly help me fix this?

Comment: is your domain actually ch.com?

Comment: it is a namesake domain since i dont want to put my original one here but rest of everything applies @RickRackow

Comment: hi, i have a question... is  ```http://domain-name/.well-known/acme-challenge/certbot-generated-file``` is accessible in browser... because your log states ```The Certificate Authority failed to download the temporary challenge files created by Certbot.``` Please also make sure that auto upgrade to https/443 is disabled on nginx else every request will be upgraded to 443 and as certificate has already expired.. it may become unreachable...

Comment: ok, because the error message clearly says that it can't reach ch.com and the respective subdomains. Is that also the case with your actual domains? If so, can you actually reach them from a different instance, eg your local machine?